# Expecting something between ')' and the 'AS' keyword

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradata-covalent, teradatasql, teradata-aster

I am trying to run the update query below in Teradata but getting an error message 'Expecting something between ')' and the 'AS' keyword. I am missing anything? I have checked some previous update and it worked for other developers in my company.

```
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET


 PRSCRBR_LAST_NM = COALESCE(M.PRESCRIBER_LAST_NAME,'ZZZZ1') AS PRSCRBR_LAST_NM,
```

Thanks

Comment: This appears to be just a fragment of some larger query, but in any case, you do have a dangling comma at the end there.

Comment: This is just part, there are other update lines after that one, but this is the only line to be updated on which I am using the COALESCE, the lines after that are straight forward

Comment: You don't need to alias your update, get rid of the `as PRSCRB_LAST_NM`.

Comment: Thanks everyone, Andrew's solution worked